# Shell in C: How to execute builtin command with fork() and execve()

Tags: c, shell

I'm trying to create a shell in C, and I'm stuck at the point of making builtin fuctions functionnal.

Here's my code:

```
int my_fork(char *line, char **env)
{
    /*char *line = arguments entered in getline() (like 'ls' for example)*/
    /*char **env = copy of the shell environment*/
    int i = 0;
    /*Get the PID for forking*/
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    /*Declaration of one string and one array*/
    char *path = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    char **tmp = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 7);
    /* my_str_to_word_array transform a string into an array of word*/
    char **arg = my_str_to_word_array(line);

    for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++)
        tmp[j] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
        /*my_getpath() search and found the PATH variable in the environment*/
    path = my_getpath(env);
    /*Then, we put the different paths in an array (paths are separated by ':')*/
    tmp = my_str_to_word_array(path);
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            /*my_strcat() put a string after another string*/
            /*Here, i put the entered command after all the paths*/
            my_strcat(tmp[j], "/");
            my_strcat(tmp[j], arg[0]);
            /*my_putstr() print a string, here, i try to print all the modified paths*/
            my_putstr(tmp[j]);
            write (1, "\n", 1);
    }
    /*i fork and exec the command*/
    pid = fork();
    execve(tmp[i], arg, env);
    /*i wait until the child process end*/
    wait(&pid);
        return (0);
}
```

The output give me a Segfault signal, and I don't know why. Valgrind don't help me, and I don't know what to do now ...

The error I have: "Access not within mapped region 0x0". This error happen in 'my_strlen()', functions which count the length of a string. I've searched why I have this error, and I don't understand, because at the end of my string, I'm sure to have '\0'.

my_strcat():

```
char    *my_strcat(char *dest, char *src)
{
    int i = 0;
    int len = my_strlen(dest);

    for (; src[i] != '\0'; i++)
        dest[len + i] = src[i];
    i++;
    dest[len + i] = '\0';
    return (dest);
}
```

my_strlen():

```
    int my_strlen (char *str)
    {
    int i = 0;
    while (str[i])
        i++;
    return (i);
    }
```

So, to sum up, I want to make built-in functions functional, and I have an error in my_strlen(), it's not the only error I have, but for now, let's keep eyes on this one.

Comment: You should probably add `my_strcat` that is using `my_strlen`. Looks like your accessing something you shouldn't.

Comment: Yeah, i've edited the previous post. Thanks.

Comment: Finally, what about `my_str_to_word_array`? Also print `path` in your program (after `my_getpath`) and post the result here, to make sure it's what you expect and so we can understand what and how you are processing.

Comment: Just a quick note, there should be zero reason to do an `exec` call for a shell built-in. You may not even need to `fork` unless you plan on running it concurrently.

Comment: I'm coding a minishell in C, and I have to make the buit-in functions like ls work in. It's a project of my school, and I'm authorized to use only fork and execve to be able to do this, and I didn't found another solutions ... -_-

Comment: You don't execute a built-in function with `exec...`. You execute some code in the shell itself, that's why it's called a *built-in*!

Comment: `char **tmp = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 7);` `for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++) tmp[j] = ...` How do you plan to stuff 30 things in a place that has room for 7?

Answer (score 0):

my_str_to_word_array():

```
char **my_str_to_word_array(char *str)
{
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int m = 0;
        int len = my_strlen(str);
        char **tmp = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 10);

        for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
                tmp[n] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
        while (j < len) {
                m = 0;
                while ((str[j] == ':') || (str[j] == ' ') || (str[j] == '\n'))
                        j++;
                while ((str[j] != ':') && (str[j] != ' ') && (str[j] != '\n'))
                        tmp[i][m++] = str[j++];
                tmp[i][m + 1] = '\0';
                i++;
        }
        tmp[i] = NULL;
        return (tmp);
}
```

my_getpath():

```
char *my_getpath(char **env)
{
    int i = 0;
    char *tmp = NULL;
    int len = 0;

    while (my_strncmp(env[i], "PATH=", 5) != 0)
        i++;
    len = my_strlen(env[i]);
    env[i][len + 1] = '\0';
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(char) * my_strlen(env[i]));
    my_printf("Path found\nLen: %d\n", my_strlen(env[i]));
    my_printf("Path: ");
    my_putstr(env[i]);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    tmp = my_strncpy(tmp, env[i], 5);
    return (tmp);
}
```

my_strncpy():

```
    char *my_strncpy (char *src, int n)
{
        int i = 0;
        char *dest = malloc(sizeof(char));
        int len = my_strlen(src);
        for (; n <= len; i++) {
                dest[i] = src[n];
                n++;
        }
        dest[i] = '\0';
    return (dest);
}
```

The print of path after getpath() gives me a Segfault, and when I look with valgrind, it tells me it's because of my_strlen().

But when I don't print it, it works, so I don't think it's because of my_strlen().

Output:

> Path found
>   Len: 124
>   Path: PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/tyrone/.local/bin:/home/tyrone/bin
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

When I see this, I think it's in my_strncpy, but I don't see where the error can be.

Comment: the malloc of dest is wrong i think you meant malloc(n*sizeof(char))

Comment: does it changes anything ? I already changed it to malloc(sizeof(char) * my_strlen(src))

Comment: well without the n*sizeof(char) you allocate only 1 char and tries to use more hence the seg fault but if it keep doing the segfault maybe the bug is also elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

There are some other problems with your code that will also end up causing you problems.

First, this code is incorrect in its use of `fork()`:

```
/*i fork and exec the command*/
pid = fork();
execve(tmp[i], arg, env);
/*i wait until the child process end*/
wait(&pid);
    return (0);
```

When `fork()` works, there will be *two* processes afterwards.  One where the return value held in `pid` is zero.  That is the newly-created child process.  In the original parent process, `pid` will be the process id of that newly-created child process.  (If `pid` has a value of `( pid_t ) -1`, that means the call to `fork()` failed - that will only be returned to the original parent process).

So your code needs to do something like this:

```
pid = fork();

// parent process
if ( pid == 0 )
{
    execve(tmp[i], arg, env);

    // if you get here, execve() failed and you need
    // to be really careful because you're now running
    // a copy of the parent process - you can corrupt
    // files open in the parent, for example, because
    // data can be buffered in FILE * streams.

    // this is safe, though.  Note the underscore!
    // exit(0) without the underscore is *not* safe here
    _exit(0);
}
// child process
else if ( pid > ( pid_t ) 0 )
{
    wait(&pid);
}
else
{
    // fork() failed - handle error
}

return (0);
```

Also, when you allocate an array of strings like this:

```
char **tmp = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 7);

for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++)
    tmp[j] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
```

and then do this:

```
tmp = my_str_to_word_array(path);
```

you just leaked all the memory you allocated by overwriting the value returned from the `char **tmp = malloc(...);` call to `malloc()`.  And once you leak that, you leak all the memory allocated in the `malloc()` calls located in your loop.